# Annoying IE8 dropdown issue in XP but not windows 7

Tags: javascript, css, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have an annoying issue with a select html element that cuts off the text in the dropdown when it is longer then the set width of the select html element.

The select elements need to be a set width to stop the page misalinging, Every browser seems to work except for IE8 running on XP. why? so random and bad compatibility.

please let me know if you need more infomation.

Thanks!

Comment: If the text won't fit, what is the browser supposed to do?  Are you sure that you're getting the same font in XP as you are in Win 7?

Comment: in other browsers the dropdowns adjusts to the correct width, while the select element stays the same width.

Comment: Oh wait - I know what you're talking about now.  IE just does that; sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's a how IE interprets it should render the drop downs ... Unfortunately,there's no easy fix, what you can do is create a replacement for drop downs that handles this in a different way, that can work consistently across browsers ...

Here's a solution I came up with

http://weblogs.asp.net/jaimedelpalacio/archive/2008/11/22/custom-html-dropdown-control-part-1.aspx

Comment: is there a Dojo way of doing this?

Comment: Ive never used Dojo, but I suspect there should not be too much problem to port the script part to dojo... The rest stays the same

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure of the differences between OS, but just use conditional comments to style the select in IE. style the  as well.